# Is it possible to extract empty folders with jar xf?

Tags: jar, directory, extract, unzip

I use `jar xf file` in a script to unzip a zip-file, which also contains empty folders but the empty folders are not extracted. Is it possible to extract empty folders with `jar xf file`?

**Edit:** In fact it works as Mike Slinn pointed out in the answer. I have now noticed that the empty folders actually turn into empty files when I use another zip-file which was not created by myself. What could be the difference between the empty folders in those zip-files? I use Windows 10 and JDK 1.8.0_144 64 Bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here is proof:

```
$ mkdir empty # create an empty directory

$ jar -cf ~/junk.jar empty ./cache # add the empty directory and other directory to a new jar

$ jar -tf ~/junk.jar # list the contents of the jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
empty/
cache/
cache/ssh/
cache/ssh/hostkeys

$ mkdir blah # make a temporary directory

$ cd blah # move to the temporary directory

$ jar -xf ~/junk.jar # extract the jar into the temporary directory

$ l empty # verify that the "empty" directory exists and is actually empty
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 mslinn mslinn 4096 Dec 24 19:42 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 mslinn mslinn 4096 Dec 24 19:43 ../
```

Comment: Please accept my answer and ask a new question if you desired